# is there possible to save .xls file in angular if data coming from api in coded form. how?

Tags: angular

I am working on a project in which I have to save data as .xls formate and data is coming from the backend API in coded form or some stream data. so, is it possible to do this? if yes please let me know how to do this. 
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver/v/1.3.2). Send response as a byte stream from your backend and make the following request

```
 this.http.get(url,{ responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe((respBlob: any) => {
    saveAs(respBlob, `file.xls`)
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several things to keep in mind:

First in the new Version XLSX it is a zipped file that inludes several files.
You can save as base format always a tabed or a comma seperated text file (csv,tsv,ssv). Even it is possible to open xml files in Excel.

In other programming languages u always need a libary to do this, cause excel have a special structure.

To do this over a blob function might be the wrong way. Blob is normaly only a placeholder for files - a special field wich normally save and hold files in theyer original format.

cheers